# Prevent other users to get Whatsapp notification

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, privacy, push-notifications

Is there is any way to prevent other users to get notification when I joined Whatsapp?

Apparently, I don't want others to announce I'm using it as I'm trying to join it for only selective friends and family members.

Comment: Are you sure they are getting notified? I must say I never heard of it.

Comment: When I join Whatsapp, those who have my number they're getting push notification as I've joined it before. I'm not sure it is still the same but I highly doubt it changed.

Comment: Never happened to me.

Comment: I have been using WhatsApp since 2014~ and I've never seen this. Perhaps there are 3rd-party tools or modded WhatsApp that have this feature, but unless proven otherwise, it's unclear if this really happens (screenshots of the notification would certainly help).

Answer (score 1):

Users don't get a notification or the like, when you join WhatsApp. (Maybe you're mixing up with telegram where users do get notified?)

But, when someone who has your number will try to send you a WhatsApp message, they will see that you have WhatsApp.

To prevent them from seeing that you have WhatsApp, you'll have to either block their number in WhatsApp or open a WhatsApp account with a new number that no one knows.

Comment: I also thought about Telegram. Never heard of such thing on WhatsApp